# HTML Select field in many rows

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a page with an html table which has 5 columns and the last 2 should have "select" html element.

I generate one "select" element without any problem but I need that select element in every row. I doubt a good approach is to copy/paste the select element in each row.

What would be a good way to display that select element in every row?

My table rows are like this :

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
?>
    <div class="row">
        <span style="visibility: hidden" class="cell" data-label="TransacID"><?php echo $row['cc_id '] ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="TransacDate"><?php echo $row["cc_transac_date"] ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="ListingDate"><?php echo $row["cc_listing_date"] ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="Description"><?php echo $row["cc_description"] ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="Amount"><?php echo $row["cc_amount"] . "$" ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="Category"><?php echo $row["cc_category"] ?></span>
        <span class="cell" data-label="CategoryType"> *** THE SELECT ELEMENT IN EACH ROWS ***?></span>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that actually builds the `select` element.  Considering that is the main point of your question, I don't understand why that's the one thing that you _didn't_ included.

Comment: Hi Patrick, my problem is more related to how can I reuse the select element possibly a thousand time? I will edit mympost when i get home, to try to better explain my question. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem.  You _should not have_ 1000 rows on one page.  No user in the world will appreciate that.  Look into implementing some form of pagination.

Comment: Hi Patric, I redid my whole page, using bootstrap and, as you said, some pagination, with the help of tutorials. Thanks for your feedback!